# How to pass string as variable name assignment

Tags: python, variables, dynamic, variable-assignment

I have a SDF data file which stores variables names and their values in block format.

The values in side the `varNameList` are names of variables (strings) corresponding to which a data block is there inside the sdf file and it can be accessed only by giving these variable names.

I read the data file and variables using the following code in ipython

```
import sdf
import numpy as np
dataFile = sdf.read('0010.sdf')

varNameList = dir(dataFile)  
varSize = np.size(varNameList)  #gives the array size
vName = 'dataFile.'+np.str(varNameList[51])+'.data'
```

The outputs of variable names is as follows:

```
In [71]:varNameList[51]
Derived_Number_Density_electron

In [72]:vName
'dataFile.Derived_Number_Density_electron.data'
```

Now, I wish to use this string on the right side of an assignment e.g.

```
electronDensity = dataFile.Derived_Number_Density_electron.data
```

If I write this line in a standard Python program, it reads the data and assigns it to electronDensity.

However, in my simulations, these variables are dynamically created and their names can be found using `dir()` command as written above. I am not able to create a program line equivalent to

```
electronDensity = dataFile.Derived_Number_Density_electron.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate an expression from a string in Python.  Here's a simple example:

```
>>> x = 123
>>> y = "x"
>>> z = eval(y)
>>> 
>>> print z
123
```

In your case, you can do:

```
electronDensity = eval(vName)
```

Comment: ***`eval()` is very dangerous!!***

Answer (score 0):

Using [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) without argument, you can access local variables as a dictionary. Or you can also use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

Mixing with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get arbitrary attribute using attribute name:

```
vs = vName.split('.')
varname = vs.pop(0)
value = vars()[varname]
for v in vs:
   value = getattr(value, v)

electronDensity = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I did the following and it worked.
This way, even if I don't know what are the vaiables created in every simulation run, my post-processing python-script will take care of the dynamically created variables at runtime of simulation.

```
path = '/home/ajit/run/data/0001.sdf'
datafile=sdf.read(path)
varNameList = dir(datafile)   #reads all the variable names
varNameSize = np.size(varNameList)
varName=[0 for i in range(varNameSize]
varData=[0 for i in range(varNameSize]

for i in range (0, varNameSize):
      varName[i] = 'q.'+np.str(varNameList[i])+'.data'
      varData[i] = eval(varName[i])
```

Thanks again.